# Как составить запрос к mysql для поиска возможных друзей?

Tags: sql, php, mysql

У меня есть таблица friends, в которой добавляются двунаправленные связи между пользователями. К примеру если пользователь с id равным 1 добавил пользователя с id равным 2, а пользователь с id=2 в свою очередь подтвердил, что он является его другом то в таблице появляются два значения. Общая структура выглядит так:

```
 user_id    |    friend_id    
    1               2               
    2               1                
    3               1               
    1               3               
    3               4               
    4               3               
    2               6   
    6               2
    3               6
    6               3
```

Я пытаюсь определить возможных друзей для пользователя от количества вхождений общих друзей друзей из списка друзей пользователя.

К примеру для пользователя с id=1 возможными друзьями будут, пользователи с id=6 и id=4

Я пытаюсь получить что-то наподобие этого:

```
 user_id    |    Possible id    |    id common friends      |    Total common friends    
                 (friend_id)
    1               6                       2                           2
    1               6                       3                           2
    1               4                       3                           1
```

Что бы можно было отсортировать по количеству общих друзей от максимума к мнимому и определить наиболее вероятного возможного друга.

Сейчас это реализовано с помощью нескольких запросов из php, но хотелось бы оптимизировать этот момент, но пока что решение я так и не смог найти.. И возможно моих знаний в этой области не достаточно...

Может у кого нить есть идеи, как сделать такой запрос?

Comment: Вообще для таких вещей удобнее использовать графовые БД и соответствующие алгоритмы. Там вообще много интересного.

Главный недостаток графовых БД — они совершенно неспособны заменить другие БД (реляционные, колонко-ориентированные, документ-ориентированные… тысячи их) там где те хорошо справляются. Так-что графовые БД приходится использовать параллельно с обычными и синхронизировать с ними.

Answer (score 1):

Можно одним запросом

```
    select users_with_same_friends.user_id, users_with_same_friends.same_friends_count
    from (
        select user_id, count(friend_id) as same_friends_count
        from friends
        where
           friend_id in (select friend_id from friends where user_id = 1)
           and user_id <> 1
        group by user_id
    ) as users_with_same_friends
    order by users_with_same_friends.same_friends_count
```

Comment: результат

 user_id same_friends_count
 4 1
 6 2